How I make a button change color when I press in React Native?
My button does not change color. Here s my code:
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const MyButton = () => {
  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = React.useState(false);

  const handlePressIn = () => {
    setIsPressed(true);
  };

  const handlePressOut = () => {
    setIsPressed(false);
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPressIn={handlePressIn}
      onPressOut={handlePressOut}
      style={[styles.button, isPressed && styles.buttonPressed]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Press Me</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  buttonPressed: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default MyButton;

What am I doing wrong? Button does not change color.
I am trying to change the color when the button is pressed.
Expecting the button to turn red but it stays blue.

I'd like to clarify what your actual goal is. Do you mean that when pressing the button it should stay red ,then after releasing the button press you want it to return to blue?
Or are you thinking of it more like you can toggle between colors on each click? I'm quite confused, since you mention that you "Expect button turn red but stay blue on press, but your code implements press-in and press-out."

Yes! The first one!

I think inherently, using TouchableOpacity will be tricky in solving this, so I wouldn't recommend using it for this case since it already has it's own behavior to handle the touch feedback. What you're looking for is like below but using react-native's Pressable component instead and it's just simple like so:
<Pressable
  style={({pressed}) => [
    styles.button,
    {
      backgroundColor: pressed ? 'red' : 'blue',
    },
    styles.wrapperCustom,
  ]}
>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Press Me</Text>
</Pressable>


pressed can be useState value @Anastasios3

hmm, why would you need it as a state? , by default it's already handled internally https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/Libraries/Components/Pressable/Pressable.js#L91, can you elaborate further ?

Here is where it's set specifically https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/93c079b92a028354cb7926b2029601238bf82d7d/packages/react-native/Libraries/Components/Pressable/Pressable.js#L296

Actually, I said this as additional information, I don't usually use pressable, but I will examine the source you posted. thanks Jojo
